# Android accessing SDK attributes in XML

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, attributes

I'm trying to extend Android's `simple_list_item_2`, so I copied the XML of it, which is:

```
<TwoLineListItem xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:mode="twoLine"
    android:paddingStart="?attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
    android:paddingEnd="?attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd">

    <TextView android:id="@id/text1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItem" />

    <TextView android:id="@id/text2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/text1"
        android:layout_alignStart="@id/text1"
        android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItemSecondary" />

</TwoLineListItem>
```

The problem is, in my implementation, the line

```
    android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItemSecondary"/>
```

gives the error:

`Cannot resolve symbol ?attr/textAppearanceListItemSecondary`

I tried stuff like:

`android:textAppearance="android:?attr/textAppearanceListItemSecondary"`

and

`android:textAppearance="@android?attr/textAppearanceListItemSecondary"`
but it doesn't work

So my question is, how can I access the same symbol/attribute that a layout in Android SDK resources can access? Do I need to copy the symbol to my application directory, or can I simply access the one that `simple_list_item_2` does?

Also, the original `simple_list_item_2` is located in `C:\Android\sdk\platforms\android-23\data\res\layout\` and my implementation of it is located in `\app\src\main\res\layout` if it helps

Comment: Ugh, I just googled this, came here, and then realized this is my own question I asked last year

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSecondary"
```

[Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html#ReferencesToThemeAttributes)

You need to place the `?` before the package name, not after: `?[<package_name>:][<resource_type>/]<resource_name>`

> **Referencing style attributes**
>   A style attribute resource allows you to reference the value of an attribute in the currently-applied theme. Referencing a style attribute allows you to customize the look of UI elements by styling them to match standard variations supplied by the current theme, instead of supplying a hard-coded value. Referencing a style attribute essentially says, "use the style that is defined by this attribute, in the current theme."
>
> To reference a style attribute, the name syntax is almost identical to the normal resource format, but instead of the at-symbol (@), use a question-mark (?), and the resource type portion is optional. For instance:
>
> `?[<package_name>:][<resource_type>/]<resource_name>`

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Comment: Hi Соколов, and welcome to Stack Overflow! About your answer; your code might be correct, but with some context it would make a better answer; for example, you could explain how and why this proposed change would resolve the questioner's problem, perhaps including a link to the relevant documentation. That would make it more useful to them, and also more useful to other site readers who are looking for solutions to similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access private SDK attributes, so you you have to copy them.

It might be possible in code using reflection, but certainly not in xml.